# Creating a 3D Plot of a Polynomial Function with Uniform Distributed Values

Tags: r, polynomials, rgl

I have an equation which goes like this,

```
2* (1-x-a-b)^2 * x * *theta* + 2 * (1-a-b-x) * x^2 * *theta*  - 2 * b * x^2 + 2 * a * (1-a-b-x)^2 = 0
```

I want to create a function in R, that selects `a` and `b` with restriction `(a + b < 1 - a + b)` from an uniform distribution. After selecting, I want it to find the solutions for `x` (both negative and positive).

I want to repeat this process `t` amount of time in a for loop where I will give the `theta` value as an input.

After that I want it to create a 3D density plot where solutions are shown with respect to values of `a`,`b` on two axes and `x` on one axis.

So far I have tried to use `polynom` package and `solve` function. But I am having hard time with R when it comes to mathematics.

Comment: @user2554330 Thank you so much ! I will check it out. I'm sorry for type I have used the package named "polynom". Here is the link for R documentation, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/polynom/polynom.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rewrite the polynomial in standard form `a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + a3*x^3`, then you can use the base function `polyroot()` to find the roots.  For example,

```
a0 <- 2 * a * (1 - a - b)^2
a1 <- 2 * (1 - a - b)^2 * theta - 4 * a * (1 - a - b)
a2 <- -4 * (1 - a - b) * theta + 2 * (1 - a - b) * theta - 2  * b + 2 * a
a3 <- 0
```

So this is a quadratic equation, not a cubic as it appears at first glance.

Then use

```
polyroot(c(a0, a1, a2))
```

to find the roots.  Select the real roots, and put them together into a matrix `roots` with columns `a, b, root`, then use `rgl::plot3d(roots)` to display them.

I think you have a typo in your restriction, so I'll ignore it, and this is the plot I get for `theta == 1`:

```r
theta <- 1
a <- runif(1000)
b <- runif(1000)

a0 <- 2*a*(1-a-b)^2
a1 <- 2*(1-a-b)^2*theta -4*a*(1-a-b)
a2 <- -4*(1-a-b)*theta + 2*(1-a-b)*theta-2*b+2*a

result <- matrix(numeric(), ncol = 3, dimnames = list(NULL, c("a", "b", "root")))
for (i in seq_along(a)) {
  root <- polyroot(c(a0[i], a1[i], a2[i]))
  if (max(Im(root)) < 1.e8)
    result <- rbind(result, cbind(a[i], b[i], Re(root)))
}
library(rgl)
plot3d(result)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Most of the roots are really small, but for some of them `a2` is nearly zero, and then they can be very large.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table with a column for each variable and filter the rows not satisfying your equation:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1337)
n <- 1000

tibble(
  a = runif(n),
  b = runif(n)
) |>
  filter(a + b < 1 - a + b) |>
  expand_grid(
    theta = seq(0, 1, by = 1),
    x = seq(0, 1, by = 1)
  ) |>
  filter(
    2 * (1 - x - a - b)^2 * x * theta + 2 * (1 - a - b - x) * x^2 * theta - 2 *
      b * x^2 + 2 * a * (1 - a - b - x)^2 == 0
  )
#> # A tibble: 0 × 4
#> # … with 4 variables: a <dbl>, b <dbl>, theta <dbl>, x <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Unfortunately, there is no point in the sampled space satisfying your equation. This is probably due to `==0` instead of `<e` where e is a very small error. One needs to allow small errors in numerical sampling solutions.

Why just not solve the roots of the equation analytically?

Comment: I think filtering isn't an option since, as you mentioned, there exist a very small amount of errors. Maybe I can use polyroot package. If you mean by hand by analytically I don't think it is possible on a short time interval. Nonetheless your function seems working, it can be altered with polyroot package. I will keep this topic updated.